# 400 Bad Request JQuery WCF Service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, wcf, web-services

I created a WCF web service in ASP.NET 4.5 in VS2012 that returns a JSON response.
The service works fine with the built in webservice client and I got the endpoints set up correctly in the Web.config file.

On the client side, I have a simple test script in Jquery, however, after running the script, I get a HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request.

The web service requires no input at all - so data: is set to an empty string.

Here is what I get when calling the service (using HTTP Live Headers add-on in FireFox).

```
http://localhost:58234/CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD

OPTIONS /CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58234
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: http://localhost:59099
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcc2l0ZXMyXENyeXB0b0NvaW5TZXJ2aWNlc1xDQ1NWQy5zdmNcR2V0X0JUQ0VfQlRDX1VTRA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 23 Dec 2013 16:08:27 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#btnRefresh').click(function () {

       $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:58234/CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD',
            data: '',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                ServiceFailed(msg);
            }
        });


        function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
            alert("success");
        };

        function ServiceFailed(result) {
            alert("fail");
        };


    });




});
```

naturally, it fails. I've tried several different combinations with no luck and POST, as well as GET.  crossDomain true/false, processData true/false, etc. nothing seems to work.

Here's the CONTRACT for the webservice:

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
Function Get_BTCE_BTC_USD() As TradeData
```

This appears to be a problem with the request, but the error does not indicated what that might be.

Here is the inside of the web.config in the WCF service:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="CryptoCoinServices.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior" name="CryptoCoinServices.Service1">
        <!-- leave address empty for localhost -->
        <endpoint
            address="" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            contract="CryptoCoinServices.IService1"
           />
        <endpoint
          address="mex"
          binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Here are recommended changes in the jQuery script (still doesn't work, but the {} for the data is mandatory, apparently):

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:58234/CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (msg) {
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            ServiceFailed(msg);
        }
    });
```

New Error after change to webHttpBinding:

```
http://localhost:58234/CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD

OPTIONS /CCSVC.svc/Get_BTCE_BTC_USD HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:58234
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Origin: http://localhost:59099
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 513
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcc2l0ZXMyXENyeXB0b0NvaW5TZXJ2aWNlc1xDQ1NWQy5zdmNcR2V0X0JUQ0VfQlRDX1VTRA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 23 Dec 2013 17:02:44 GMT
```

Comment: Show us the server-side config! If you can easily test your service in a the WCF Test Client, it's most likely a **SOAP**-based service - but jQuery usually requires a **REST** based service (with a `webHttpBinding`)

Comment: As suspected - your using `basicHttpBinding`, a **SOAP**-based binding - which works great, just not in conjunction with jQuery. You'll need to look into the `webHttpBinding` and how to leverage that in your service, so that your jQuery client can call your service method

Comment: I added the web.config contents.  Yes, indeed it is setup as JSON/REST as you can see from the CONTRACT decoration. Are there more configurations?

Comment: ok - I'll try the webHttpBinding

Comment: replace  data: '' with  data: '{}',

Comment: webHttpBinding creates an internal server error and does not work with the Test Client either.

Comment: The 500 Internal Server Error looks like it is due to the Request Method "OPTIONS" - there is NO such method in HTTP 1.1 specification!

Comment: @MC9000:You are doing cross domain communication.Please see the log in firebug or chrome developer tool

Comment: where is the Firebug log? I have it installed on FireFox.  Should I set crossDomain to false? (i'm going to try that now)

Comment: no just press F12 function key and see the server log on console tab

Comment: hmmm. F12 works, but there's no server log. I'm going to try to reinstall FireBug - I have version 1.12.5

Comment: nope - i have the latest version. Are you sure it's firebug? I just use the Tools --> Web Developer --> Web Console, but it doesn't say WHY there's a 500 error, the Event Viewer shows nothing either. FireBug shows DOM, CSS, JS and other stuff, none of which indicates anything useful for this error.

Comment: crossDomain set to false has no effect. Perhaps WCF is just not compatible w/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

As your are doing cross domain communication and by default WCF does not support cross domain communication.Check out following link for complete example

[Calling cross domain wcf service using Jquery](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.in/2012/02/calling-cross-domain-wcf-service-using.html)

Comment: okay - I'll check this out. I had no idea it was this involved in WCF :(

Comment: geek, is that a console app? just curious.

Comment: no, it's not that either - the author is missing too much code to create a working example. He did provide clues in the config file, however. Another day, another lock of hair pulled from head.

Comment: ALAS! The only example on the Internet that ACTUALLY WORKS!!!https://berniecook.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/consuming-a-wcf-service-with-jquery-or-scriptmanager/

Comment: I spoke too soon. the author's example only works locally (you can't share it on the Internet as written). More experimentation to follow.

Comment: Anyone out there have any more ideas?  I'm all out of them.

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample WCF and it works with the scenario you explained. However the code is in c#. You can try the below config and code.

```
  namespace WCF
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "Testing")]
    //[ServiceContract]
    public interface ITestWCF
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        String HelloWorld();

    }
}



namespace WCF
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService2" in both code and config file together.
    class TestWCF : ITestWCF
    {
        public string HelloWorld()
        {

            return "Hello!!!";
        }

    }
}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "Service1.svc/rest/HelloWorld?",
            type: "POST",
            data: "{}",       
            success: fnsuccesscallback,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: fnerrorcallback,
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>   
<client />
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>        
  <service name="WCF.TestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFBehaviour">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:1991/Service1.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ITestWCF" behaviorConfiguration="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour" name="httpEndpoint"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF.ITestWCF" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"  binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestWCFEndPointBehaviour">
      <!--<enableWebScript/>-->
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Please note that i have exposed a endpoint with webHttpBinding and i have named it **rest**

You can also refer http://www.wcf.dotnetarchives.com/2013/12/invoking-restful-wcf-service-with_20.html